# Matching exact numbers with regex

Tags: python

I am trying to write a regex to match a pattern like

```
7777-555-999
```

The pattern is valid only if all four digits are same as first digit like 7777.If first digit is 6 then first four digits should be 6666 . similarly for next 3 and the last 3. How to match exact digit as first.kindly update

Comment: try `(\d)\1{4}`

Comment: how can we modify this to digits in increasing order. like 789-345-234. What regex would work for this.

Comment: What do u mean? so u want to replace the numbers in `7777-555-999` with their incremented value? Pls post the demo input and output pls...

Comment: no the input now is 789-345-234 and it should be validated only if numbers are in consecutive order i.e 789 or 123 or 345 like this. how to write regex for it.

Comment: i think it is a little bit challenging, it can be only done by putting all the possible combinations into a regex like [`(?:(?:012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)[\s-]){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/b1k6UT/1) i'll update you later if i find something like that in a regex way rather than this type of finding text by their all type of combinations